# android don't show icon after first launch...?

Tags: android

i have a small problem: can i show the icon of my application in drawer only so long as it is done the first time?

I found the code (in the manifest to make) for don't appear (icon is invisible):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SanvalentinoNumActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <!-- ICON INVISIBLE -->
            <data
                android:host="mocha"
                android:path="/RTT/reset"
                android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

but i would like that or my app autostar afetr the downloading or that the icon become invisible after the first launch..

help me please...

Comment: You want the user to only be able to run your application once?

Comment: my app is them for other app...

Comment: i solved it:

PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it: PackageManager p = getPackageManager(); p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Answer (score 0):

Keep a database to automatically increase a integer value. initialize it to 0 if its greater than 0 execute the following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,0);
```

Comment: i solved it:

PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

but after try your solution